# How to remove all queued jobs because it's causing errors?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

My website queues email sending jobs to the `jobs` table. I think the email server has some problem and it can't send emails so the jobs are stuck at the jobs table. Now maybe there are too many jobs, and I receive this error message:

```
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `reserved_at` = 1510263884, `attempts` = 256 where `id` = 342)' in /var/www/vhosts/parcgilley.com/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
#0 /var/www/vhosts/parcgilley.com/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(607): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('update `jobs` s...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/parcgilley.com/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(477): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('update `jobs` s...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/parcgilley.com/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(416): Illuminate\Database\Connection->affectingStatement('update `jobs` s...', Array)
```

So I am wondering how do I flush all the queued jobs to clear the table? I can't access the database to remove the data in the table, so is there any command line to do so? I don't have a failed queue table.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are using database driver you can use:

```
DB::table('jobs')->delete();
```

to delete all the jobs.

The other thing is that you should always run queue worker with attempts set:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

Also remember that whenever you change your application code, you should restart your workers:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

( I assume you use supervisor that will start workers again).

Comment: if i have direct access to the DB (via phpmyadmin) can i simply `delete * from jobs`?

Comment: @bondythegreat Yes, there shouldn't be any problem with this. But just in case you can restart queue

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, will `php artisan queue:restart` work even queue's being handled by supervisor?

Answer (score 5):

You can use clear command:

```
php artisan queue:clear
```

Comment: Thank you, this works when I use another driver for jobs rather than DB, like Redis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> php artisan tinker

and then

> DB::table('jobs')->delete();

this work !!!