# local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1

Tags: laravel-5.5

Hi have you encounter similar problem in queue jobs?

I got this error on testing environment online.

```
[2019-06-28 01:55:20]

local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `reserved_at` = 1561701319, `attempts` = 256 where `id` = 510) {"exception":"[object]
(Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `reserved_at` = 1561701319, `attempts` = 256 where `id` = 510) at
/home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664,
Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 at
/home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:119,
PDOException(code: 22003): SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 at
/home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117)

[stacktrace]
#0 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('update `jobs` s...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(490): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('update `jobs` s...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(423): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->affectingStatement('update `jobs` s...', Array)
#3 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2173): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->update('update `jobs` s...', Array)
#4 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(287): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->update(Array)
#5 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(268): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->markJobAsReserved(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJobRecord))
#6 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(198): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->marshalJob('refund_export_t...', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJobRecord))
#7 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(244): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->pop('refund_export_t...')
#8 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(105): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue), 'refund_export_t...')
#9 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'refund_export_t...', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#10 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'refund_export_t...')
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#12 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#14 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#15 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#16 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#17 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#18 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#19 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(969): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /home/forge/default/releases/20190628053028/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 {main}
"}
```

While running locally works fine?

How did you solved it?

Comment: Searching for your error msg [turns up](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25612) several [things](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24636) which [describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212165/how-to-remove-all-queued-jobs-because-its-causing-errors) you need to specify `tries`.  Did you find those, and try that?

Comment: I diagnosed the problem and found out that truncating table `failed_jobs` fixed the problem, the reason is that it can't  process what is in the `failed_jobs`

Comment: Hey @Fil I have same problem now. If you have solution please share with me. Thanks

Comment: does any one have any solution on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in the attempt col datatype